# Is it possible to extract / copy the content of a VHDX file

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-10, vhdx

I have recently created a Raspian VM using Hyper-V on Windows 10 so I can start learning the OS as part of a personal project.

What I would like to be able to do is take the content of this VM image and drop it onto an SD card, plug it into a Raspberry Pi.

Is this possible? I'm a developer and tech savvy, though have little experience with VM's on my own machine or handling the files.

As a side Q - how can you navigate to the folder containing the *.VHDX files: Mine are in the default location C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V - I can navigate to this with a command line, running as admin but windows explorer will not open the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you technically can convert a *.vhdx file to a raw disk image (e.g. under Linux using `qemu-img convert -f vhdx -O raw <image>.vhdx <image>.img`), it still won't boot on a Raspberry Pi, because your virtual machine is likely Intel/AMD CPU architecture and your Raspberry Pi is ARM CPU architecture. Aside of that, both architectures have different boot concepts.

Note that Hyper-V is a virtualization hypervisor, not an emulator for another CPU/hardware architecture. You can verify this yourself if you run `uname -m` on your Rasbian in the virtual machine. If it returns `x86_64`, it's Intel/AMD CPU architecture and won't boot on Raspberry Pi (which is ARMv7 and/or ARMv8, depending on the exact model).

Comment: Oh, wow. I had not considered the actual hardware that deeply at all. I really appreciate your help.